# How to bind images from TreelistEx to a repeater in Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but still went ahead.
The template has these fields

```
Description [Rich Text]
Images      [TreelistEx]
```

User will select pics from the media library using the TreelistEx field, which later would be displayed in a carousel. User should also be able to edit those images.

My code is not displaying any images.

**aspx:**

```
<div class="toggle_1bs">
  <asp:Repeater ID="rpImages" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpImages_ItemDataBound"    
  ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <div id="1bs" class="owl-carousel">
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="item">
     <sc:Image ID="imgMain" Field="Images" runat="server" CssClass="img-full"  
     Item="<%#Container.DataItem %>"/>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
     </div>
  </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

**aspx.cs:**

```
private void BindData()
{
  //bind data to the repeater
  MultilistField offerImages = (MultilistField)offerDetails.Fields["Images"];
  rpImages.DataSource = offerImages.GetItems();
  rpImages.DataBind();
}

protected void rpImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  var mainItem = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;

  if (mainItem != null)
  {
   var imgMain = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgMain");

   if(imgMain != null)
   {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mainItem)))
       imgMain.DataSource = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mainItem);

       //Response.Write(MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mainItem));
    }
   }            
  }
```

There are 2 images added using the treelist control and I can see the html rendered for the 2 images (`<div class="item"></div>`).

Answer (score 3):

You don't have field which is an `Image` type field. That's why you cannot use `sc:Image` like that.

You're getting list of media items from your TreeListEx.

Remove your `rpImages_ItemDataBound` and try something like this instead:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <img src='<%# Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem)) %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That did display images, but user can't edit them. In order to make images editable, I think I should add each image as an item & then use `sc:image`. Is that right. Any other way?

Comment: Since your repeater has an item type, you can just call the item directly like this. Does this display editable images? Also, can you debug this line and inspect the item. Is there a field called Images on the item?

<sc:Image ID="imgMain" Field="Images" runat="server" CssClass="img-full" Item="<%#Item%>"/>

Comment: As I wrote above, you cannot use `sc:image` with treelist. You should read about Edit Frames and custom buttons.